# Not being able to run NestJS application

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm-install

I don't know what happened but I'm not being able to run a NestJS application locally
What I've tried so far:

- deleting node_modules
- deleting package-lock.json
- npm i --save-dev @types/node
- gave up and git cloned the whole application in a different folder (that runs on my colleagues' machines but not mine, they couldn't figure it out either)

I've been losing my mind, any help is appreciated

NPM Version 8.5.4

Node.js Version v16.14.2

tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "paths": {
      "<rootDir>/": ["."]
    },
    "incremental": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.build.json:

```js
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "__mocks__", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "REDACTED",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "check-env": "node -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register src/checkEnvs.ts",
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist && npm run check-env",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node --max-old-space-size=2500 dist/src/main.js",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:noCov": "jest --watch --collectCoverage=false",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "prisma:create": "npx prisma migrate dev --create-only",
    "prisma:run": "npx prisma migrate dev",
    "prisma:generate": "npx prisma generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@elastic/elasticsearch": "7.10",
    "@nestjs/bull": "^0.4.2",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.1.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/elasticsearch": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/event-emitter": "^1.0.0",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^8.1.2",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.0.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.4.4",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^1.1.0",
    "@ntegral/nestjs-sentry": "^3.0.7",
    "@prisma/client": "^3.14.0",
    "@sentry/node": "^6.17.3",
    "@sentry/types": "^6.17.3",
    "amqp-connection-manager": "^3.7.0",
    "amqplib": "^0.8.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bull": "^3.29.3",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "cli-progress": "^3.10.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.27.0",
    "fast-csv": "^4.3.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.10",
    "nestjs-ftp": "^0.1.13",
    "nestjs-soap": "^2.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@golevelup/ts-jest": "^0.3.2",
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/bull": "^3.15.7",
    "@types/cli-progress": "^3.9.2",
    "@types/cron": "^1.7.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.179",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/sax": "^1.2.3",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.2",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "leaked-handles": "^5.2.0",
    "mongodb-memory-server": "^8.4.2",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "prisma": "^3.14.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone finds this question pulling their hair out, it turned out to have been my `tsconfig.json` file, all I had to do was roll back the lib version from `"lib": ["es2020"]` to `"lib": ["es2017"],`

I wish I had seen that on my crystal ball